# How to export everything from Firefox to another PC

Tags: windows, firefox

I'm going to do a clean install of Windows 7 in my laptop and one of the thing that I really want the way it is is Firefox. I know I can get the addons easily and the bookmarks also, but I also like to export my browsing history, the Awesome Bar database and my about:config customizations.

Is there a way or tool to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109)** (Firefox Environment Backup Extension) allows you to quickly and easily backup your Firefox extensions. In fact, it goes beyond just backing up -- It will actually rebuild your extensions individually into installable .xpi files. Now you can easily synchronize your office and home browsers.

> **FEBE backs up your extensions, themes, bookmarks, preferences,
>   passwords, cookies and just about
>   everything else Firefox offers** (it
>   can even backup/restore your entire
>   profile). You can selectively restore
>   only the items you need. For instance,
>   you may just want your bookmarks
>   restored and leave everything else as
>   it was.

Features:

- One click backup from the Toolbar.
- Schedule automatic backups on a daily, weekly, or monthly basis. Can also be configured to backup on Firefox startup and/or shutdown.
- Save backups in time-stamped folders to easily identify when the backups were created. Specify how many folders you wish to keep and FEBE removes the oldest.
- Backup reminder. FEBE can alert you if a backup has not been completed in a specified number of days.
- Comprehensive results report with links to the author’s extension/theme homepages.
- User-defined backups. Make backups of virtually any file or folder - Firefox related or not. Just specify what to backup and FEBE does the rest.
- Extensive built-in help files. Just click the little blue information icons in FEBE options.
- FEBE 6.0 uses native Firefox zip/unzip components. Much, much faster than previous FEBE versions that depended on external, third-party utilities.
- Upload backups to your Box.net account automatically or with a single click.
- Verify your extension directory. Upgrading Firefox versions sometimes leaves garbage in the extensions directory. FEBE can clean it up.
- Quick Backup. You can quickly backup as many or as few individual extensions/themes as you like. They can be saved together in a single, installable xpi file (Similar to CLEO).
- FEBE 6.2 has a new, simpler profile restore interface. No need to use the Firefox Profile Manager to manually create a profile to restore into.
- … and more!

Comment: The new installation broke every Ubiquity command.

Comment: FEBE doesn't work properly on Firefox 3.6 !!!

Answer (score 4):

Use [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/).

> MozBackup is a simple utility for
>   creating backups of Mozilla Firefox,
>   Mozilla Thunderbird, Mozilla Sunbird,
>   Flock, SeaMonkey, Mozilla Suite,
>   Spicebird, Songbird and Netscape
>   profiles.
>
> It allows you to **backup and restore
>   bookmarks, mail, contacts, history,
>   extensions, cache etc.**

Comment: I've been using Mozbackup for a year now and I am very pleased with it so far.

Answer (score 1):

For an good package, along with the [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109) suggested by Molly,
check the [CLEO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109) addon too.

> CLEO (Compact Library Extension Organizer) is a Firefox extension that works with FEBE to package any number of extensions/themes into a single, installable .xpi file

Answer (score 1):

The manual way to do it:

- Copy your profile files from `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`
- Launch firefox with the profile manager: `firefox.exe -p`
- Create a new profile and choose the folder where you have copied your profile files

Comment: Better yet, you can just copy the entire `Mozilla` folder and everything works off the bat