# How to copy all of my firefox addons to another machine?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to export everything from Firefox to another PC](https://superuser.com/questions/71018/how-to-export-everything-from-firefox-to-another-pc)

I have downloaded many add ons for my PC at work and I would like to copy them to my home PC.
Is there a way to automate this process and export all the installed add-ons?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/71018/how-to-export-everything-from-firefox-to-another-pc

Comment: Somehow I didn't find it... Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an add on for that!

> [FEBE (Firefox Environment Backup
>   Extension)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2109) allows you to quickly
>   and easily backup your Firefox
>   extensions. In fact, it goes beyond
>   just backing up -- It will actually
>   rebuild your extensions individually
>   into installable .xpi files. Now you
>   can easily synchronize your office and
>   home browsers.

Comment: Is FEBE compatible with Firefox 3.6 .because it doesn't work properly for mine.

Comment: @Mohammad: From the extension's page: *Works with Firefox: 3.0 – 3.7a1pre*

Comment: You're right. But I don't know why it doesn't work properly for me :(

Comment: @Mohammad: see the other answer from Nifle - MozBackup may be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

FEBE is great and very competent (periodic backups) but can sometimes be a bit cumbersom to use. You have to install FEBE before you can import things saved with FEBE and you can't restore the current profile so you'll have to start Firefox with another profile active.

So I mostly use [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) nowdays (Windows only). In theory it's not as good as FEBE but I have had no problems with it, plus it's a lot easier to use.

> MozBackup is a simple utility for
>   creating backups of Mozilla Firefox,
>   Mozilla Thunderbird, Mozilla Sunbird,
>   Flock, SeaMonkey, Mozilla Suite,
>   Spicebird, Songbird  and Netscape
>   profiles.
>
> It allows you to backup and restore
>   bookmarks, mail, contacts, history,
>   extensions, passwords, cache etc.