# Back up the entire Firefox 4 settings

Tags: backup, firefox, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to export everything from Firefox to another PC](https://superuser.com/questions/71018/how-to-export-everything-from-firefox-to-another-pc)

How can I back-up entire Firefox 4 settings and then apply them after a clean re-install?

Comment: It doesn't specifically target firefox 4 and its sync features so i don't think it was a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a *[Firefox Sync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_Sync)* account. It synchronises your

1. Bookmarks
2. Passwords
3. Preferences
4. History
5. Tabs

And you can uninstall your Firefox, reinstall it and reconnect to synchronise and all your settings will be there.

To setup synchronisation go to the *Orange Firefox button* > *Options*> *Options* and the *Sync* tab.

Checkout [the tutorial on *Firefox Sync*](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync) for further instructions.

Just remember to store your synchronisation key temporarily as it will be needed to restore your settings on a fresh install.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Mozbackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/)